# What is the difference between "apart", "except", "other than" and "besides"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Do the following phrases have the same meaning or are there differences?

> - Fortunately, apart from a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
> - Fortunately, except for a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
> - Fortunately, other than a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
> - Fortunately, besides a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.

Comment: If anything, I think this is just a matter of semantics. They all mean the same thing; she has a broken toe, but isn't badly hurt.

Comment: Isn't "meaning" the same as "semantics" in this case?

Comment: As @Souta said, in the end it's the same. Compared to your native language: *Abgesehen von*, *Ausgenommen*, *bis auf*, *Mit Ausnahme von*. Do you see any differences?

Comment: @Souta :) if its 'just a matter of semantics', they all cannot mean the same thing. You need to make up your mind on that one.

Comment: @Em1: Yes, I see differences in the german versions. _Bis auf_ is far more colloquial than _Mit Ausnahme von_. Of course, they all mean the same (so my formulation of the question could be improved), but I wanted to get to know the slight differences in the usages of the words.

Comment: Slightly-elliptical sentences like the examples might be spoken, but in writing a verb form is likely to appear before *a broken toe*.  Eg: “Except for suffering a broken toe, she was not badly hurt.”  The lack of verb forms before *a broken toe* in the examples makes them all sound slightly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fortunately, **apart** from a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
  -- while *apart* itself is acceptable, it is awkward in this particular example.
- Fortunately, **except** (for) a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
  -- best option that conveys the meaning appropriately in the context.
- Fortunately, **other than** a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
  -- fine; can be an alternative to *except*, which is the right word in this case.
- Fortunately, **besides** a broken toe, she was not badly hurt after the car accident.
  -- inappropriate: avoid *besides* when showing an exception.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, as I've asked the question because it was in an english test where you had this sentence with the "from" and you should fill in one of the words (apart, except, other, besides). So, because of the "from" apart was the correct answer. Are you a native english speaker?

Comment: @moose Well, in that case, the idea of the question was one of **collocation** -- *apart from*, *except for*, *other than*, *besides (none)*.

Answer (score -1):

Should be "except *for*" in the second example. I think that in this case they all basically have the same meaning. I'd prefer the first three as they more strongly indicate that "a broken toe" is different to "not being hurt".

Comment: Both "except" and "except for" are, um, acceptable.

Comment: Just "except" doesn't sound right to me (in British English). I'm willing to admit I'm wrong :)

Comment: Might be a US/UK thing, true.